# force ajax to return 200 on error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to hide the exceptions thrown in the console so I want to hard-code the status code to 200 for all exceptions. In my case, I want to change a 500 internal server error response.

I know it's a bad practise but there are cases that can be used..

Comment: in what case would you want it used?

Comment: `try { } catch() { }` the error and return a valid response; can't give you much else without seeing your code.

Comment: Most of this is handled internally behind the scenes by jQuery. Whether you catch the error or alter the payload, the response will most likely be returned in the `.fail()` callback...

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs when for example the non-developer admin adds content to the cms that creates broken requests(without affecting the result) or more general, when I want to hide exceptions in the production environment

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use a try/catch. Here's a dummy example:

```
try {

  return json_encode(array(
    'code' => '200',
    'result' => array()
  ));

} catch (MissingArgumentException $e) {

  // Known exception
  return json_encode(array(
    'code' => '400',
    'message' => 'Bad request: missing argument.',
    'result' => null
  ));

} catch (\Exception $e) {

  // Default exception
  return json_encode(array(
    'code' => '500',
    'message' => sprintf('An error occured: %s', $e->getMessage()),
    'result' => null
  ));

}
```

Comment: Given this code: $.ajax({ url: "test.html" }) , where should the above code be added? .done()? Can you expand your example?

Comment: To avoid HTTP 500 statuses, you need to write server code (this exemple was in PHP). You won't be able to avoid server errors with just client-side code.